# Java set schedule and execute action using timer by minutes (Continuously running)

Tags: java

I would like to configure a java system that does schedule based on minutes but everytime it does the action, it will stop and not run the next action based on the minute.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); //this is the method you should use, not the Date(), because it is deprecated.

            int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);//get the hour number of the day, from 0 to 23
            try {

                if (min == 17) {                      
                    System.out.println("doing the scheduled task at " + min);
                    this.cancel();
                }

                if (min == 18) {                        
                    System.out.println("doing the scheduled task at " + min);
                    this.cancel();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error Occurs " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    timer.schedule(tt, 1000, 1000);//   delay the task 1 second, and then run task every one second

}
```

Kindly assist :(

Comment: Works fine for me, are you getting ay error?

Comment: what exactly you want ?... it is printing 17 on console !!

Comment: @zombie no errors but it did not run the codes when the time in minutes turn 18 minute

Comment: @sparsh610 I was expecting it to run also when the time in minutes is 18 minute however it did not

Answer (score 0):

```
if (min == 17) {                      
     System.out.println("doing the scheduled task at " + min);
     this.cancel();
}
```

> this.cancel() is the culprit

```
Here is the description
```

public boolean cancel()

Cancels this timer task. If the task has been scheduled for one-time execution and has not yet run, or has not yet been scheduled, it will never run. If the task has been scheduled for repeated execution, it will never run again.

Hope this will help